# Could not instantiate mail function ONLY with big attachments

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have a problem with my PHPMailer class.
There is a form with file upload functionality. The file uploads fine with no errors.
But I get the following output from the script:

> Could not instantiate mail function. Unable to send message to *** @ ***.com

This happens only with the attachments of more than several megabytes. My php.ini configuration is fine:

> post_max_size = 50M
>
> upload_max_filesize = 50M

When I get this value below the actual upload size, then the page just refreshes and nothing happens. With the following values the file is uploaded and stored in the temporary folder but cannot be sent as attachment.

Any help will be appreciated

PS I can send emails with attachments of 1 MB with no problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, answering my own question. Sorry for wasting anyones time.
First of all, a look on /var/log/mail.log revealed this line

> Oct  4 20:15:39 s16271040 postfix/sendmail[13663]: fatal:
>   ***@***.com(33): message file too big

That made more sense now.

We go to /etc/postfix/main.cf and add the following line to the end of the file

> message_size_limit = 20480000

And we have 20MB limit for file attachments, hooray :)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue where exim was rejecting emails larger than ~700KB.

You cannot always edit mail configuration files on shared servers. The solution I used was to use my ISP's SMTP server to send emails.

1) Create an email address or use an existing one and note down all settings including:

- SMTP server hostname and port
- Whether it requires authentication to send emails
- Credentials if the above is true

2) Instead of messing with `class-phpmailer.php` use a wordpress plugin called "WP Mail SMTP" which:

> Reconfigures the `wp_mail()` function to use SMTP instead of `mail()` and
>   creates an options page to manage the settings.

After installing the plugin, enter the information from step 1 in the plugin settings page.